# html animate comment form

Tags: html, css

I have html:

```
 <a href="#" class="addcomment">Add Comment</a>
<div id="addcomment">
<form name="comment" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="addcomment" size="80" />
<input type="submit" value="Comment"/>
</form>  
</div>
```

and my css:

```
#addcomment {
display : none;
}
#addcomment:target {
display : block;
}
.addcomment:active + #addcomment {
display : block;
position : absolute;
top : 5px;
}
```

I want to make the comment form like in stackoverflow. When I click add comment the form should appear.

When I do this and click "Add comment" the comment form appears but when I release the mouse click the form disappear only "Add comment" is shown. How can I make the comment form appear after click on "Add comment"

Comment: `:active` pseudo class is only applied as long as the mouse button is held down. Go for the `:target` pseudo class or the _checkbox hack_ (research keywords) instead, if you want a pure HTML/CSS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a checkbox and the `:checked` selector:

```css
#addcomment{
  display: none;
}
#addcomment:target{
  display: block;
}
label[for=addcommentbox]{
  cursor: pointer;
}
#addcommentbox{
  display: none; /* Prevent the checkbox from appearing */
}
#addcommentbox:checked + #addcomment{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label for="addcommentbox">Add Comment</label><input type="checkbox" class="addcomment" id="addcommentbox">
<div id="addcomment">
  <form name="comment" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="addcomment" size="80" />
  <input type="submit" value="Comment"/>
</form>
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

Comment: thats not working dude... checkbox is displayed and in case of two form whichever I click first one is opened and same prob disappear after mouse click release...

Comment: My demo works correctly. Please confirm you have the correct CSS. If you have multiple forms, use classes instead of ids.